# Jquery submit does not fire

Tags: jquery, submit

I have some code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>StarTrackr!</title>
        <script src="../../lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"
        charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('div').load('1.htm');
            // The above function does work

            $("#testform").submit(function () {
                //Code after form submitted and this does not fire
                alert("hi");
            });    
        });         
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <form id="testform">Email:
            <input type="text" name="email" />
            <br />First Name:
            <input type="text" name="fname" />
            <br />Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="lname" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>    
</html>
```

When I click on the submit button, the alert (hi)  should pop-up but it does not. Does anyone know why? Assume the Jquery library is loaded correctly

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: change `input type="button"` to `input type="submit"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `input` needs to have `type="submit"`, not `type="button"`.

Comment: Depot - Thanks!  The type=button was straight out of a book on Jquery, a typo that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Change type="button" to type="submit"